# Any idea why the param being modifed was removed from the HTML output in ZAP?

Tags: sql-injection, zap

```
http://xxx/?-d+allow_url_include%3D1+-d+auto_prepend_file%3Dphp%3A%2F%2Finput=%27+AND+4571%3D9588+AND+%27kISD%27%3D%27kISD
```

(Advanced SQL Injection)

here is the ZAP description:

> The page results were successfully manipulated using the boolean
> conditions [' AND 7750=7750 AND 'Qmxz'='Qmxz] and [' AND 4571=9588 AND
> 'kISD'='kISD] The parameter value being modified was stripped from the
> HTML output for the purposes of the comparison.
>
> Data was returned for the original parameter.
>
> The vulnerability was detected by successfully restricting the data
> originally returned, by manipulating the parameter.

Was this the server removing the HTML output, or is it the query? Is it possible to view the HTML output modified parameter in ZAP?

Comment: The use of -d allow_url_include and prepending a file is a remote code exec bug in PHP CGI (CVE-2012-1823). You can find more details on that bug at https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/cve-2012-1823/course. Same as your other question, I can only assume you're doing something rather unusual to get these false positive findings.

Comment: Many of the SQLi rules strip the param names and payloads from the response body content before comparison to reduce false positives.